# Qt Creator Compile Error (.o file not found)

Tags: c++, macos, g++, qt-creator

I've never compiled before on OS X or using g++, but after opening my project and attempting to compile I get the following error:

```
../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/include -I. -I../FATX -I. \
    -F/Users/landerbrandt/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/lib \
    -o xMultiFileStream.o ../FATX/IO/xMultiFileStream.cpp
make: g++-4.2: No such file or directory
make: *** [xMultiFileStream.o] Error 1
```

Not too sure what the issue is here since it compiles just fine under Windows (using MSVCC though, of course).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was found here:  http://developer.qt.nokia.com/forums/viewthread/12682

It appears that the solution Tobias proposed worked.

> or you can force the mkspec used by passing a “-spec macx-g++” to the qmake step (which will override the one chosen by Qt Creator).